# How to get my public ip using powershell

Tags: powershell, nslookup

I tried using nslookup but I'm unable to parse the result :

My current output :

```
nslookup -norecurse myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
Serveur :   resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

Réponse ne faisant pas autorité :
Nom :    myip.opendns.com
Address:  X.X.X.X
```

I just want the IP `X.X.X.X`

I tried using `| select` without any success, maybe the good way, or not ...

Thanks for your help, note that the goal is just to get my public ip in a easy way without any dependancies and quickly, an answer without nslookup or powershell can make the job.

Comment: "Another option is to visit the URL below and it will open a blank web page which contains your External IP in the top left.
 https://diagnostic.opendns.com/myip"

Comment: ...so try
 (Invoke-WebRequest https://diagnostic.opendns.com/myip).content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

Resolve-DnsName myip.opendns.com -server resolver1.opendns.com -type A | select -expand IP4Address

Comment: It's work perfectly, awesome ! I think that's the quicker way to get public IP address.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use one of the many free REST APIs that provide this information rather than making DNS query (which has the downside of not working if you don't use dynamic DNS). Here's an example for one of the first ones I found.

```
Invoke-RestMethod https://api.ipify.org
```

Comment: Thanks this way works perfectly, it's the simpliest, but not as speedy as pure DNS request.